# React-Native: How to create semi circle arc using a View

Tags: react-native

[image]
How can I create this shape using only a View in react native

Answer (score 1):

While this is probably doable with some fancy css or even an svg I would highly recommend using a package, compound someone else's work ya know?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-circular-progress

If you're curious about the actual mechanics you can dig into the packages source code and learn how it ticks.
https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-progress